# Is there a health risk from radiation with a laptop power supply?

Tags: laptop

My roommate often has his laptop's power supply close to him, and I am just wondering whether this can cause health problems, since there may be radiation generated by the power supply.

Comment: There is no harmful radiation coming from the power adapter.

Comment: What is wrong with a healthy problem?

Comment: At least he doesn't have a CRT monitor =p

Comment: @ekaj Surely, you mean semi-portable X-ray emitter.

Comment: @ChrisF: Maybe not radiation, but what's with the electric field? ;)

Comment: @Bobby - that's not harmful either.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: definitely not.

Long answer: do you even know what you mean by "[radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation)"? Do you know the difference between [ionizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionizing_radiation) and [non-ionizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-ionizing_radiation) radiation?

The only problem that could arise is if the power adapter got hot enough to burn him, which he would have noticed in the usual way one notices heat, and subsequently most probably moved the power adapter.

Comment: Actually, a hot power supply can become dangerous (for guys) even before it starts burning your skin away. Just google around, e.g. http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2010/11/legs-apart-under-laptop-your-sperm-will-thank-you/

Comment: @honk: No, it can become dangerous for *the boys*, that's a difference. ;)

Comment: Lest he put the power supply on his pelvis, he and his future children will be fine. At least as far as the placement of the power supply is involved.